# proving that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=g(r)f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble solving the following exercise:

> If $f(x,y)=e^{-r^{2}}$ with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, show that it exists a function $g(r)$ such that:
>
> $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=g(r)f(x,y)$$
> and determine the function $g(r)$.

When I saw this, because of the $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the first thing that came to my mind was that maybe this would be easier if we use polar coordinates, But I don't know how to approach the problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use Laplacian in polar coordinates.

Comment: I thought about that but In my class the teacher did not introduced the concept of Laplacian, so I'm afraid we are not allowed to use that. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The most direct way is of course to just calculate explicitly what the LHS is. It may be slightly tedious, but its not so bad... in fact, I did the comparison, and it took me roughly the same amount of time to perform the calculation in either coordinate system

Comment: Another small hint is to note the symmetry in $x$ and $y$; i.e $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, so really you only have to calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$, and then the one for $y$ should be almost "obvious" (or you can of course calculate that directly as well).

Comment: You're right, and the derivative is not that difficult because that square eliminates the square root in the expression of $r$. But probably there is a more elegant solution for this @peek-a-boo

Comment: To me the most elegant way is to use Laplacian in polar coordinates: $\text{Lap}(f) = \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}+ \dfrac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}$, but you said you didn't want to use this approach. So really your only other alternative is to do the direct computation, which again, in this particular case, is already pretty simple.